Regression analysis using repeated cross-sectional survey data
I have a dataset collected over 5 consecutive years using the same survey instrument. Each year’s respondents differ, but the survey questions remain identical.
I am interested in examining the relationships between several independent variables and a categorical outcome variable (Y).

Is running separate logistic regression models for each of the five years suitable?

Is it necessary to verify the profile of respondents is consistent across the five years?



Depending on your specific questions, it’s probably most efficient to add a variable called “year” and include it in your logistic model. You can also add in interactions between this variable and your predictors, though that will depend on how large your sample is (interactions are usually noisy to estimate).

@RickHass Thank you very much for your comment! I’m wondering if there’s a difference between running separate regressions for each year and running a single, combined regression that includes a “year” variable. Also, since there are about 10,000 respondents per year, would you consider that sample size to be sufficiently large?
